# How to display custom content in protected PDF files?

Tags: pdf, protected, livecycle

When a PDF document is protected with a security policy from Adobe LiveCycle ES or Adobe AEM Forms, it can only be opened by Adobe Reader. Here's what it looks like when you try to open it in another PDF viewer.

Microsoft Edge:

[image: Microsoft Edge]

Firefox (internally uses PDF.js):

[image: Firefox (internally uses PDF.js)]

But I have seen secured PDF documents that in other viewers show customised instructions to download and install Adobe Reader. Obviously there is a way to add unprotected content to protected PDF files, that other PDF viewers will display. How can I do it?

Here's an example of a PDF file I'm talking about.

When opened in Adobe Reader:
[image]

When opened in Firefox:
[image]

Comment: Could you provide us with a link to a sample document that shows the issue?  If that's not possible could we see a screenshot of the 'customized instructions to download an install Adobe Reader'?  This will help me provide a useful answer.

Comment: @JosephA I added the screenshots above. You can see that when opened in Adobe Reader, the document asks to login (I presume to AEM Forms?), and in Firefox it asks to use Adobe Reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also posted this question on Adobe forums, and someone replied with the correct answer there. AEM Forms has a feature that allows to add cover page to a policy-protected document: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/AEMForms/6.1/RMHelp/WS2d2a17056e219198-31ba356e14172797744-8000.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way to do what you are asking would be to supply the 'custom content' during initial *authoring* of the PDF with Adobe LiveCycle ES for instance.

(How this is accomplished may be similar to how it works for dynamic XFA content where the page contains some content that non-XFA compliant readers can fallback on to display instead of just erring out.)

But I think the only way to add such content to an existing PDF using non-Adobe software would involve violating the Rights Managment policy the author intended, which is not something you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not trying to modify a document that's already protected by a policy, but rather BFORE it has been protected. E.g. we modify PDF documents by adding a watermark to every page, then we apply Rights Management policy using AEM Forms. The policy (among other things) does not allow the document to be modified, which ensures the watermark cannot be removed. Now I want to make another modification before the policy has been applied - the one I'm asking about here.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I see you have been able to find the answer which is great.  Based on what is mentioned there it indeed appears to rely on fallback content being placed on the first page of the document where traditional PDF software would expect to find it.